# Visual Studio 2015 kernel debugger gets stuck

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, kernel, driver, kmdf

I am attempting to write a KMDF driver using visual studio 2015. When I try to deploy the driver and start the debugger everything seems to work: visual studio is able to build the solution and deploy it to the target computer (wich is a virtual machine), but after the deployment of the files, it seems to get stuck: I can't pause the debugger and execute the debugger's commands.

**My Question: How do I get the debugger to break/pause?**

**What I have tried:**

I have tried connecting to the target computer both  with the network and with pipes, but neither seems to change anything.

I have tried setting the test certificate to "WDKTestCert".

I have tried adding a package project to the solution.

**Additional Information:**

My configuration of the project is the exact same as shown on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439654(v=vs.85).aspx).

My host computer and target computer are both running windows 8.1 64 bit.

The target computer is a VMWare virtual machine.

I am using visual studio 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2.

I am using WDK 10.

**The Debugger's Log:**

```
Using NET for debugging
Opened WinSock 2.0
Waiting to reconnect...
[20:00:30:970]: Remove Existing Remote Package
[20:00:31:802]: Task "Remove Existing Remote Package" completed successfully
[20:00:31:824]: Copy Driver Package
[20:00:35:171]: Task "Copy Driver Package" completed successfully
[20:00:35:193]: Driver Removal
[20:00:35:194]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[20:00:36:057]: Copying required files for "Driver Removal".

$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks_downlevel.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverRemoval'" /p:"InfFile=KmdfDriver.inf" /p:"Debug=1" /p:"ImportDriver=1" /p:"RemoveDriver=1" /p:"CertificateFile=KmdfDriver.cer" /p:"PackageGuid=x64" /p:"HardwareId=Root\KmdfDriver" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Driver_Removal_00008.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[20:01:51:745]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[20:01:51:750]: Task "Driver Removal" completed successfully
[20:01:52:183]: Driver Preparation
[20:01:52:184]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[20:01:53:029]: Copying required files for "Driver Preparation".

$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks_downlevel.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverPreparation'" /p:"InfFile=KmdfDriver.inf" /p:"Debug=1" /p:"ImportDriver=1" /p:"RemoveDriver=1" /p:"CertificateFile=KmdfDriver.cer" /p:"PackageGuid=x64" /p:"HardwareId=Root\KmdfDriver" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Driver_Preparation_00008.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[20:02:07:150]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[20:02:07:154]: Task "Driver Preparation" completed successfully
[20:02:07:866]: Driver Install
[20:02:07:867]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[20:02:08:709]: Copying required files for "Driver Install".

$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks_downlevel.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_RunProcess'" /p:"BinaryPath=%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\devcon.exe" /p:"Arguments=-f install %SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Drivers\KmdfDriver.inf Root\KmdfDriver" /p:"WorkingFolder=%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Drivers" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Driver_Install_00008.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[20:02:22:809]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[20:02:22:813]: Task "Driver Install" completed successfully
[20:02:23:267]: Driver Post Install Actions
[20:02:23:268]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[20:02:24:107]: Copying required files for "Driver Post Install Actions".

$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks_downlevel.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverPostInstall'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Driver_Post_Install_Actions_00008.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[20:02:36:377]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[20:02:36:380]: Task "Driver Post Install Actions" completed successfully
```

After this point it seems like nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved ? if so please let me know the solution of how to proceed